# How can I search for and highlight multiple strings in VIM?

Tags: vim, colors, search

In VIM, how can I search for multiple strings and have a different color highlight for each match?

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075387/in-gvim-how-can-we-search-and-highlight-while-keeping-the-previous-search-highli

Answer (score 3):

There is [MultipleSearch plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=479) for vim. Description:

*MultipleSearch allows you to have the results of multiple searches displayed
on the screen at the same time.  Each search highlights its results in a
different color, and all searches are displayed at once.  After the maximum
number of colors is used, the script starts over with the first color.*

Answer (score 3):

You can use this matching commands...

```
:sy[ntax] match {group-name} [{options}] [excludenl] {pattern} [{options}]
```

if you wants to search and highlight **Apple** with **Red** color and **Mango** with **Green** and **Grape** with **Blue** use this:

```
:highlight col1 guibg=Red guifg=White
:syntax match col1 /Apple/
:highlight col2 guibg=Green guifg=Black
:syntax match col2 /Mango/
:highlight col3 guibg=Blue guifg=White
:syntax match col3 /Grape/
```